# GridLayout + Mouse Listener

Tags: java, swing, mouse, listener, grid-layout

Okay guys I have a problem, I dont know how know which cell was clicked on a grid layout, is there any function?

I have grid layout on container, for 10 rows and 10 columns, and what I want is a mouse listener to all the cells, so when I click cell (2,1) it would say which cell I am clicking because of the mouse listener.

Any clues? thanks alot in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a MouseListener to the Container that uses GridLayout and that holds the components in the grid. Then on mousePressed use the MouseEvent object, say called myMouseEvent, to get the point of the click and call `getComponentAt(myMouseEvent.getPoint);` to get the clicked component. No muss no fuss.

For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.*;

public class TestComponentAt extends JPanel {
   private static final int ROW_COUNT = 10;
   private static final int W = 60;
   private static final int H = W;
   private static final Dimension PREF_SIZE = new Dimension(W, H);
   protected static final Color SELECTION_COLOR = Color.pink;
   private JPanel selectedPanel = null;
   private Color originalColor = null;

   public TestComponentAt() {
      setLayout(new GridLayout(ROW_COUNT, ROW_COUNT, 1, 1));
      setBackground(Color.black);
      for (int i = 0; i < ROW_COUNT * ROW_COUNT; i++) {
         JPanel panel = new JPanel();
         String name = String.format("[%d, %d]", 
               i / ROW_COUNT, i % ROW_COUNT);
         panel.setName(name);
         if (i == 0) {
            originalColor = panel.getBackground();
         }
         panel.setPreferredSize(PREF_SIZE);
         add(panel);
      }
      addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
         @Override
         public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            JPanel panel = (JPanel) getComponentAt(e.getPoint());
            if (panel == null || panel == TestComponentAt.this) {
               return;
            }
            if (selectedPanel != null) {
               selectedPanel.setBackground(originalColor);
               selectedPanel.removeAll();
               selectedPanel.revalidate();
               selectedPanel.repaint();
            }
            selectedPanel = panel;
            selectedPanel.setBackground(SELECTION_COLOR);
            selectedPanel.add(new JLabel(selectedPanel.getName()));
            selectedPanel.revalidate();
            selectedPanel.repaint();
         }
      });
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("TestComponentAt");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new TestComponentAt());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer , this is what I want! Thanks mate, now I know how to do it :D
Can u just explain me somethings u made ?
LIKE this:
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });

I tested only with createAndShowGui(); inside the main and also works good :s

And why this? 
if (panel == null || panel == TestComponentAt.this) {
               return;
            }

I didnt understand when u use TestComponentAt.this , why ?
The panel wouldnt be always null ? why if (panel == null || ..)

Thanks mate!

Comment: panel could possibly be null if you click off of a component, but more likely it will be the container itself which is why I have the second check -- I don't want to use the panel if it is the container.  Regarding invokeLater, you'd best google the Swing tutorial on that one as it will take some explaining, but the gist is that you want to make Swing calls on the EDT or event dispatch thread only.

Answer (score 0):

You can work with the width an height of your container, get the width an height of container and divided it to the number of cells and find the range of the cell(2,1),for example if width and height of container equal to 100 and number of rows,column=10*10 then the left coordinate of cell(2,1) is x=10,y=0 and by method getX() and getY() of the mouseListener class you find the location of mouse clicked, then if the x and y of mouse location in the range of cell(2,1) you can know that it clicked on the cell(2,1).
[image]

Comment: Thanks mate ;)
I am on my way to the solution :)

Answer (score -1):

recursively add a mouselistener to all Components in your UI and debug...