# GetComponentAt Trouble

Tags: java, swing, grid, jpanel, mouselistener

I have having issues with getcomponentat in layered situation. I have researched a lot and found the following thread which is actually what I need but it does not work for me. I downloaded the code in the thread and it works but when I implemented it in my project it does not. I may be doing something really stupid mistake which I can't put my finger on.

I have a JFrame which has a base Panel. I have added a gridPanel (which extends JPanel on it and implemented mouselistner. On the grid panel I am adding cells (which extends JPanel and also implements mouselistener). when I click on any cell I want to know the position of that cell in the grid but everything comes back as 0,0.

[GridLayout + Mouse Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8127418/gridlayout-mouse-listener)

so here it goes.

```
MAINCLASS 
mainFrame = new JFrame("Connect-4");
basePanel = new JPanel();
gridPanel = new Grid(); //Grid extends JPanel

//GRIDCLASS
public class Grid extends JPanel implements MouseListener {
public Grid(){
    //      setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600,700));;
    setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 7));
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            Cell tempCell = new Cell(i,j); //Cell Exntends JPANEL
            tempCell.addMouseListener(this);
            gridUI[i][j] = tempCell;
            gridTrack[i][j] = 0;
            add(tempCell);

            int index = i*6 + j;
            cellArray.add(tempCell);

        }

    }
    addMouseListener(this);
}
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println("Grid Click");
    Cell clickedCell;
    Boolean filled = false;

    Point mousePoint;

    mousePoint = e.getPoint();
    System.out.println(mousePoint.x + "||" + mousePoint.y);
    clickedCell = (Cell)getComponentAt(mousePoint);


    //      Point mousePoint = MouseInfo.
    int cellIndex;
    cellIndex = Integer.parseInt(clickedCell.getName());
    int cellX = cellIndex / 7;
    int cellY = cellIndex % 7;
}


public class Cell extends JPanel implements MouseListener{

private String status; 
private Color curColor;
private Boolean occupied;
public static Boolean gameOver = false;
public static int player;
public static boolean randPlayer = false;
private Color player1 = Color.BLUE;
private Color player2 = Color.RED;
private static int[][] gridTrack = new int[6][7];
public int row,column;
public static int cellSize = 80;
public Cell(int row_in, int column_in){
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(cellSize,cellSize));
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK, 3));
    setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    player = 0;
    this.setName(Integer.toString(row_in*6+column_in));
    curColor = Color.WHITE;
    addMouseListener(this);
    occupied = false;
    player = 1;
    row = row_in;
    column = column_in;
    gridTrack[row][column] = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the Listener is fired, the point of the event *relative to the Component* that fired the event. Adding `MouseListener`s to a `Cell` results in the coordinates being relative to that `Cell` - as a result using `getComponentAt` on the parent `Component` with these coordinates will always return the `Cell` at 0,0 as the coordinates of the Point of the event will never be greater than the width/height of a Cell.

Consider using a **single** listener to handle the behavior, using the appropriate technique to get the Component that fired the event:

1. Add  a listener to the parent `JPanel`- the coordinates of the event are relative to the parent. Thus using `getComponentAt` will return the Component where the `MouseEvent` occurred
2. Add a listener to each `Cell`, and get the `Cell` that fired the event using `Cell cell = (Cell)e.getSource()`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Just got busy with some stuff so have not incorporated this yet. Will let you know how it went !

Comment: ok it works. But I need some guidance again. I removed the MouseListner from class Cell  and in Grid class got the cell by calling e.getsource. after every mouseclick I check the grid for a winner and when someone wins I want to put the message on UI. The message box is in PlayConnect class. I am using MouseListener here (it was working earlier). To my surprise only MouseEntered and MouseExited methods are called but not clicked and others. What can be reason? The only change in code from original question is removal of Interface from Cell.

Comment: Given your code has changed, and this seems to be a different problem than before consider asking a new question as debugging through comments like this presents challenges.

Comment: posted another question..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30199007/mouselistner-not-triggering